# Creating an Array from the Contents of a Large Folder Quickly

Tags: arrays, ruby, directory

I'm trying to create a workflow that uses an array from a specific folder's contents, however the folder has over 150k contents and thus the process is extremely slow, I am currently using the Dir.entries method to create the array, but need to drastically decrease the time it takes.

Here is my current code:

```
Dir.entries('directory/to/search')
```

It simple and straightforward, but not very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the the names of all directories + files under a specified path you can use unix level commands like:

```
path = 'directory/to/search'
`ls #{path}`.split("\n")
```

There are way faster:

```
# . directory has 30 entries in this example
Benchmark.measure { Dir.entries('.') }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fe6ab92aee8 @label="", @real=7.675203960388899e-05, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.0, @total=0.0>

Benchmark.measure { `ls`.split("\n") }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fe6ab8f9a50 @label="", @real=0.00298881100025028, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.0, @total=0.0>
```

I hope it helps